# How to refresh parameter returning by a function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having problem on DevExtreme datasource and actually this question already sent to them and still being discussed. But I am wondering if I am missing something basic in Angular.

DevExtreme introduce a AspNetData source control which makes communication with .NET API very easy. It accepts Options object where you can define additional parameters. In my scenario, I have defined "firmaId" loadParams which takes value via function.

The function "getFirmaId()" simply returns "firmaId" variable.
selectTab(e) function is being hit by clicking a tab controller. It gives a new value to "firmaId" succesfully. But when I load DataSource by using DevExtreme client API, loadParams of "firmaId" is always 0. Is it working as it is expected? In my opinion, this is contradicting functional programming concept of JavaScript.

Any help appreciated.

```
firmaId: number;  

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {  

    this.firmaId = 0;

    this.dataSource = AspNetData.createStore({  
      key: "id",  
      loadUrl: Constants.apiRoot + "/api/cari/get",  
      insertUrl: Constants.apiRoot + "/api/cari",  
      updateUrl: Constants.apiRoot + "/api/cari",  
      deleteUrl: Constants.apiRoot + "/api/cari",  
      loadParams:  { firmaId : this.getFirmaId() },  
      onBeforeSend: function(method, ajaxOptions) {  
          ajaxOptions.xhrFields = { withCredentials: true };  
      }  
    });  
  }  

  getFirmaId():number{  
    return this.firmaId;  
  }  

  selectTab(e) {  

    this.firmaId = e.itemData.id;  
    this.dataSource.load();  

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through what's going on here. The constructor fires and you create the store, calling `this.getFirmId()` which returns 0 at this point. When a tab is selected, `this.firmId` is correctly updated and you load the data source.

The problem you have is that it's not likely running `createStore` again when you call `this.dataSource.load()`, meaning it never calls `this.getFirmId()` to update the value. You can confirm this by logging within the `getFirmId` function to see if it's firing. If not, you'll need to figure out how to update the dataSource before calling load again.

```
selectTab(e) {  
  this.firmaId = e.itemData.id;
  // update param here 
  this.dataSource.load();  
}
```

Comment: Hello, you are absolutely right. createStore is not running when I load dataSource. If I createStore again within selectTab(e), everything works fine. I knew this solution already but I am not sure If I am creating unnecessary objects which cause garbage. Because user will click Tab control many times to select different companies. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: if you're overriding `this.datasource` each time I can't imagine it'd be an issue. they may provide a way to update it without calling create again (I'm not familiar with the tool so idk), but if not that's what you'll have to do